# Qt dll error with opencv

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm trying to run a program to display an image using opencv but I get the following errors:

```
file not recognized: File format not recognized
C:\opencv\release\bin\opencv_ffmpeg249_64.dll

error:Id returned 1 exit status
File not found: collect2.exe
```

.pro file:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = myFirstOpenCVProject
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
CONFIG   -= qt

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C://opencv//release//install//include

LIBS += C://opencv//release//bin//*.dll

#LIBS += C://opencv//release//lib//*.a

LIBS += -LC://opencv//release//lib -llibopencv_core249 -llibopencv_highgui249 -llibopencv_imgproc249

OTHER_FILES += \
    img.JPG
```

main.cpp

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>


int main()
{
        // read an image
        cv::Mat image= cv::imread("img.jpg");
        // create image window named "My Image"
        cv::namedWindow("My Image");
        // show the image on window
        cv::imshow("My Image", image);
        // wait key for 5000 ms
        cv::waitKey(1000);
        return 1;
}
```

The image(img.jpg) is in the appropriate directory; where the project executable is. I tried removing the dll and the code ran without errors but it did nothing and just showed a shell prompting me to hit return.

[image]

Comment: can you please try to hardcode the full image path (with `/` or double-backslashes if in windows)? The `imread` didnt work (wrong path, corrupt file or imread is broken), so the mat you want to display is empty.

Comment: please change to `cv::waitKey(0);` (waits until you press a key) and `return 0;`  (return 1 means error)

Comment: are you building in debug mode or in release mode?

Comment: please try `imread("img.JPG")` according to your proj file

Comment: Hardcoding the full path worked, i was i release mode. Thanks, could you post an answer for me to accept, also how did you identify the error?

Comment: typically image size is only 0 if the image could not be loaded. That's typically because of a wrong (relative) path. You should accept the answer of GPPK since he solved your initial `.dll` question. For the path problem you could edit your question and add the solution at the end, since it's just a minor problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem

```
LIBS += C://opencv//release//bin//*.dll
```

This line makes you include all the .dll files that are in the bin folder for OpenCV. You don't want to do this.

---

You may just be able to remove this line and it will work I am unable to test. Failing that see below

---

What you want to do is include only the dll files for the code you are using. The matching DLLs for

- core
- highgui
- imgproc

something like this would work for OpenCV 2.4.9 debug (remove the last d for release libs):

```
LIBS += C://opencv//release//bin//opencv_highgui249d.dll
LIBS += C://opencv//release//bin//opencv_imgproc249d.dll
LIBS += C://opencv//release//bin//opencv_core249d.dll
```

Comment: do the dlls have to be added at all?

Comment: hmm you could be right. It might just be a case of removing the *.dll line completly

Comment: I replaced that line with `LIBS += -LC://opencv//release//bin -llibopencv_core249 -llibopencv_highgui249 -llibopencv_imgproc249` now the code runs but crashes immediately.

Comment: without the error its hard to debug. However if you are building in debug then add d to your libs i.e -llibopencv_core249d

Comment: I get no errors or warnings in qt. However the prompt that opens when I run the code gives an opencv error relating to the size and height of the image. Is there a limit to what opencv can open? Sorry I hit enter before I finished typing